# Translate English sentences in statement logic

Tags: logic, logic-translation

The task is: Give agood translationof the following puzzle into formal statement logic.

```
1. Paul doesn’t like logic or Quincy likes it.
2. Robert likes logic, only if Quincy doesn’t like it.
3. Paul and Quincy like logic, if and only if Paul likes logic and Robert
does not.
4. Paul likes logic and if Robert likes logic then also Quincy.
5. Additionally (1 extra point): Who likes logic and who not?
```

I did the task but I don`t know if it is done correct. Please can somebody check?

My answers:

```
1. ¬p ∨ q
2. p ↔ ¬q
3. ((p ∧ q) ↔ (p ∧ ¬r))
4. p ∧ r → q
5. p ∧ ¬p
```

Comment: (2) should only have an arrow in one direction. Maybe (4) should have parentheses? I think (5) is actually asking you to use (1)-(4) to determine who likes and who doesn't like logic.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it comprises multiple separate questions.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I disagree on this being multiple _separate_ questions. Question 5 is dependent on the answers of the previous questions.

Answer (score 1):

(1): good
(2): $\leftrightarrow$ is for if-and-only-if. Only-if is for a one-sided arrow.
(3): good
(4): should be $(p \land r) \rightarrow q$, else it's ambiguous to read.
(5): In this puzzle, you need to use all the statements. I'll do this one:

From (4) we know that Paul likes logic. Then we go to 1: this can only hold if Quincy likes logic. So Quincy likes logic. So from (2), Robert doesn't like logic (this uses the **contrapositive**!).  All of this is consistent with (3). Done!

Comment: Eh, I'm not too sure about my answer on (4) anymore.

Comment: I would probably write (4) like p ∧ (r → q). 
I don`t know if I can leave this statement without any parens at all, or there should be one anyway?

Comment: I think writing it like $p \land (r \rightarrow q)$ leads to inconsistency in the system.

Comment: Is it possible to leave it without any parens at all? If not (p∧r)→q and not p∧(r→q), then how...

Comment: I said I'm not too sure about my answer on (4). I don't know if it's wrong. I'm very tired. You'll have to check it and see if it makes sense.